# perl fileparse and push into multiple arrays

Tags: perl, perl-data-structures

I have an array that contains file paths. I would like to split the array to give me the file_name, dir_name and the extension. I am trying to use File::Basename perl module.

Can someone help me achieve this:

```
foreach (@files) {
    push((@file_basename,@dir_name,@ext), fileparse($_));
}
```

I know what I am doing is not right.. Can someone help me fix the above piece of code?

I know I can do this:

```
$filename = basename($file);
```

and then push this value into an array. Similarly do the same for dir and the extensions. Just looking for a better way.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Running your code, I get : `Not an ARRAY reference at ./push.pl line 13.` I'm guessing it's complaining about `(@file_basename, @dir_name, @ext)` not being an actually array. Other people have given a more proper use of `push` and `fileparse`, chrsblck and amon

Comment: Thanks @kjprice I knew the code was not working. I was looking for an elegant solution in one line. Thanks for you help..

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're missing the 2nd parameter to `fileparse`. Which is `@suffixes`

Stated in the [perldoc](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Basename.html), for what you're looking for should look like this:

```
my($filename, $directories, $suffix) = fileparse($path, @suffixes);
```

If you don't have a list of suffixes, you can do something like this:

```
fileparse("/foo/bar/baz.txt", qr/\.[^.]*/);
```

Which should match any extension.

Then you can fix the push like so:

```
for my $file (@l){
    my ($name, $path, $suffix) = fileparse($file, qr/\.[^.]*/);

    push @name_list, $name;
    push @path_list, $path;
    push @suffix_list, $suffix;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This is an interesting problem. The simplest solution is just to write it all out:

```
for (@files) {
  my ($name, $path, $suffix) = fileparse($_);
  push @file_basename, $name;
  push @dir_name,      $path;
  push @ext,           $suffix;
}
```

---

We could throw away all clarity and loop over array references, pushing the corresponding scalar onto the end:

```
my @collectors = \(@file_basename, @dir_name, @ext);
for (@files) {
  my @parse = fileparse($_);
  push @{ $collectors[$_] }, $parse[$_] for 0 .. $#collectors;
}
```

---

Or we could define a `push3` function:

```
sub push3 (\@\@\@@) { # use (+++@) prototype on p5v14 or later
  my @arrays = splice @_, 0, 3;
  ARG: while (1) {
     for (@arrays) {
       push @$_, shift;
       @_ or last ARG;
     }
  }
}
```

Or a more general `multipush`:

```
sub multipush($@) { # maybe use (+@) on p5v14 or later
   my $arrays = shift;
   ARG: while (1) {
     for (@$arrays) {
       push @$_, shift;
       @_ or last ARG;
     }
   }
}
```

Then:

```
for (@files) {
  push3 @file_basename, @dirname, @ext, fileparse($_);
}
```

Or

```
for (@files) {
   multipush [\( @file_basename, @dirname, @ext )], fileparse($_);
}
```

But I consider this solution to be inelegant, inflexible, and would advocate using the first and explicit solution.

---

To actually get a suffix instead of the empty string from `fileparse`, you have to specify regexes that match suffixes (extensions), like `qr/\.[^.]+\z/`.